# Header's height to margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header with `position: fixed;`
 but the content that is after it remains behind the header.
I've tried with JS to set the `margin-top` of the content with the header's height but doesn't work.

Here you have the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>       
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetini.css">
    <script src="javas.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>    
<body onscroll="scrolling()">
    <div class="header">
    <p>Example</p>
    </div>                      
    <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut orci arcu. Morbi in neque libero. Pellentesque in tortor magna. Nam tempus suscipit sem id viverra. Duis blandit, massa sed tristique pharetra, mauris arcu convallis quam, id rutrum urna elit tristique mauris. Duis condimentum mi vel libero consectetur tempor. Ut tempor odio vitae neque varius, nec finibus leo rhoncus.
    </div>              
    <div class="footer">
        ExampleExample
    </div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #DFB36D;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {

}
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).onload(){
        var headerHeight = $('.header').height() + 'px';
        $('.container').css('margin-top', headerHeight);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.
[https://jsfiddle.net/nxhoqcz9/](https://jsfiddle.net/nxhoqcz9/http://)

Actually removed `<center>` tags and `.` from body

Comment: Are you able to provide a JSFiddle of this so we have a visual representation of what is happening?

Comment: you use jQuery, but i can`t see, that you load this library to your project

Comment: I suggest use http://getbootstrap.com Bootstrap framework for developing advanced level website.

Comment: Just remove `.` from `.body` in your CSS. Also your Fiddle is broken

Comment: Please accept someone's answer. Otherwise, there will be so many answers

Comment: I needed to wait 2 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to remove `<center></center>` from your HTML
2. In the CSS, remove the dot before `.body` -> that's why `text-align: center;` isn't working
3. Do you have jQuery in the page?
4. Syntax for JS is incorrect

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #DFB36D;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headerHeight = $('.header').height() + 'px';
    $('.container').css('margin-top', headerHeight);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>       
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetini.css">
    <title></title>
</head>    
<body onscroll="scrolling()">
    <div class="header">
        <p>Example</p>
    </div>      
    <div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut orci arcu. Morbi in neque libero. Pellentesque in tortor magna. Nam tempus suscipit sem id viverra. Duis blandit, massa sed tristique pharetra, mauris arcu convallis quam, id rutrum urna elit tristique mauris. Duis condimentum mi vel libero consectetur tempor. Ut tempor odio vitae neque varius, nec finibus leo rhoncus.
    </div>              
    <div class="footer">
        ExampleExample
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="javas.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the $ sign, but you did not reference the JQ library

Answer (score 0):

your js code has problem...
try to fixed it like the below code

```
$(function() {
  var headerHeight = $(".header").height() + "px";
  $(".container").css("margin-top", headerHeight);
});
```

or

```
window.onload = function() {
  var headerHeight = $(".header").height() + "px";
  $(".container").css("margin-top", headerHeight);
};
```

https://codepen.io/linjiyeah/pen/NjJXNo <--- you can see the result here

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need javascript to fix this?
Just give margin-top in container.
Working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wjmdxm)

```
.container {
  margin-top:200px
}
```

Comment: I want it to be proportionally depending on the size.

Comment: Updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmEZqP).
Use document.ready function of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onload` function in jQuery. You can put it in `ready` function when document is ready.  You can write it this way without changing any of your styles.

```
$(function(){ // You can also write $(document).ready(function({ // code}) like this
    var headerHeight = $('.header').height() + 'px';
    $('.container').css('margin-top', headerHeight);
})
```

Check here: https://plnkr.co/edit/hTUg5ANMifkPoc2z8lwW?p=preview